# The clue is hidden in this statement

Tags: wordplay

"The clue is hidden in this statement", read the note handed to Sherlock by Moriarty, who hid the stolen treasure in one of the ten pillars. Which pillar is it?

Comment: I've edited the title to make it more specific. You can always rollback if you want to.

Comment: No problem at all, I think this title suits more. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's in the

> ninth: hidde**n in th**is statement

Answer (score 11):

its in

> IX.... hidd**en** **in** this...
> (read it from back... enin---> nine)

Comment: Wow, two different methods for the same outcome. +1

Answer (score 2):

My guess and reasoning is as under.

> It's in ninth pillar, hidde$N \  IN \ TH$is contains ninth.

Comment: -1 This is a duplicate of the existing answer. Idk if @Sunny did this on purpose, but it's surprising that the answer got 2 upvotes anyways.

Comment: I don't think so, anyone do this purposefully. Why anyone will do this? We are not giving any rewards for answer, so why one would cheat.

Answer (score 1):

according to the statement I think answer is one of(f) ten i.e. IX

Comment: "Of" and "Off" are very different words.

Comment: But the note says that " The answer is hidden in this statement", so I think we should look for answer in that line only.

Comment: Anyways nice observation.

Answer (score -1):

The clue is hidde**n in th**is statement. So correct Answer is 9th.

Comment: This question was already answered a month and a half ago.